# Should I be worried about Room Database's performances?

Tags: android, performance, android-room

I am working with room database in a GPS app using Sygic SDK for the GPS part adding my custom overlay on top.

The user enter the app, select a trip (which is get from the remote server) and then start it with Sygic Navigation. The trip can have up to 1000 stops and last up to 8 hours.

A lot of data is collected during the trip, stored in the database and then periodically sent to the remote server for the trip to be analysed.

I did start the app 2 years ago with plain Java without room and a custom MVC made at the time.

We made the move to Kotlin, MVVM and room for the better and we are starting to rework the navigation part.

I initially planned to store the whole itinerary (up to 1000 stops with various metadata for each) inside room database so that my state is preserved for the whole trip and I would have a single source of truth (the database).

But one of my engineer said that he was worried about performance and said that in his previous job they would only use Room for very specific data.

I know that SQLite has an absurd limit of 18446744073709551616 rows but that might be very impractical and I'm pretty sure that my UI would be negatively impacted for overusing Room wayyyyyyyy before we reach this number.

What would you do if you were in charge ? Start loading everything in the DB or keep an in memory state inside a repository and refetch whenever the Android system decide that this memory is not yours anymore ?

Do you have any examples about heavy Room workflows and can you provide insights about how it would performe in this case ?

Comment: There is no such thing as a Room database.  Room is an ORM library.  The database underneath it could be anything, but in Android is going to be SQLite.  But the performance of searching, reading, and writing will be based on the SQLite part, the Room layer would be minimal.

Comment: That said, 1000 rows is nothing.  I wouldn't worry about that at all.

Comment: Why the number of rows would affect the UI? You are not going to display 18446744073709551616 rows at the same time. So the question is how fast you can query a "page" of rows. Populate a test db and find your numbers.